# Differences between for and foreach in JavaScript 5

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I learned that a `for` iterates on each the array's element, even if a pointed case doesn't exist, while a `forEach` skips the unexisting cases.

Moreover, when a `for` is writen, a counter must be specified (I'm not speaking about `for...in`), while a `forEach` just uses a function iterator.

Well. Could you answer to the four following questions please ?

1. Does really a `forEach` skips unexisting arrays' cases while a `for` doesn't ?
2. Does a `forEach` uses an intern counter (we just don't have to write it) ? Or is it a totally different mechanism than a `for` ?
3. In some languages, a `forEach` doesn't go through an array in the same order than the array's order. What about JavaScript
4. Finally, are there other differences between them (exclusing, of course, grammatical/syntaxical ones) ?

Comment: reading the docs would have answered most of your issues. [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ... [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` keyword is a language construct, this is the fastest and most "raw" way to iterate over things. It has three styles:

1. The C-style `for`: `for ( initializer; condition; iterator ) { code... }` - this one is the most flexible and time-tested version. To iterate over a list, you start going over all list indexes from 0 to the list's length. You can also 
   go over every other, third etc element. Most of the time, this is good enough.
2. The Javascript `for-in` `for (var key in object) { code ... }` - this one is a good way to go over every key in an object, for example, to output all values of a JSON object.
3. (ES2015) The Javascript `for-of`: `for (var item of collection) { code ... }` - this one is new and available in modern browsers. It lets you skip the indexes and counters, and lets you walk over every item of a collection. (Say, every object in a products list.) It does the same thing as the C-style for, but is easier to use.

However, the `forEach` function is specific to `Array` objects in Javascript, and lets you run a function for every item in an array. It's good if you have an utility function that does all the work for you.

Here's how to use all of the above kinds of iteration:

```
// most plain kind of array with a length of 7
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, undefined];
// a weird kind of array with no values between index 3 and 100
// its length is 102 
var mySparseArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
mySparseArray[100] = 5;
mySparseArray[101] = 6;

// 1. C-style for
// ** can control how index is incremented
// ** needs an extra variable to iterate with
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(myArray[i]);
    // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, undefined
}

for (var i = 0; i < mySparseArray.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(myArray[i]); 
    // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, undefined, undefined, ... (up to index 100), 5, 6
} 

// 2. for..in
// ** keys are iterated over in non-guaranteed order
//    (you might get 2, "length", 1, 0, 3)
// ** all enumerable keys are included, that might include things other than indexes. 
for (var key in myArray) {
    console.log(myArray[key]);
    // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 
}

for (var key in mySparseArray) {
    console.log(mySparseArray[key]);
    // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    // this for-loop "thinks" the array is an object with numbers for keys
}

// 3. for..of
// ** only available in browsers with ES2015 support
// ** supports many other things than Arrays - TypedArrays, Iterators...
for (var item of myArray) {
    console.log(item);
}

for (var item of mySparseArray) {
    console.log(item);
    // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, undefined, undefined, ... (up to index 100), 5, 6
}

// 4. forEach
// ** calls a function for each element (considered slow)
// ** supports only Arrays (unless you call it with Array.prototype.forEach.call)
function myCallback(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
myArray.forEach(myCallback); // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
mySparseArray.forEach(myCallback); // logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Make sure to try these out in your browser's developer console! You can see each of the above pieces of code in action.

Make sure to check out [the MDN reference on iterations.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements#Iterations)

Comment: Regarding the skipping, OP means specifically not existent properties, not just ones with an `undefined` value. And `.forEach` does indeed skip those, try a sparse array.

Comment: `length` shouldn't be enumerable, so it's not iterated by `for...in`.

Answer (score 3):

So, when you're talking about a `for` loop you mean an actual `for` loop, not `for...in` (which should not be used on arrays). There seems to be a slight misconception and let me start off with that:

A `for` loop is *not* meant to loop over arrays. Not that you shouldn't or it's bad but that's not it's primary function - it literally just loops until a condition is met then it stops. The most common syntax happens to be `for (var i =0; i < max; i++)` which happens to match well for array looping but that doesn't mean that you can't have, say, `for (var i = 100; Number.isInteger(i); i = i/2)`. So, with that said, here are answers to your questions:

## 1. Does `forEach` skip missing items in the array?

### Answer: Yes

`forEach` is an array method and along with `map`, `reduce` and others it *does* skip unassigned slots. This is to aid in working with sparse arrays, for example

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "five";
arr[7] = "seven";
arr[10] = "ten";

console.log("---using forEach---");
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});

console.log("---using a for-loop---");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

This is a simple example that illustrates why you might want to use the sparse array loop - as you can see, you get way less code executions. Here is a slightly more elaborate one:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "five";
arr[42] = "the answer";
arr[9001] = "over nine thousand";

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

A straight `for` loop will have executed (literally) over nine thousand times, when all you have is three items.

I have to clarify something here - *unset* values are any indeces you have not assigned anything to. Assigning `undefined` does count as assigning still:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "five";
arr[7] = undefined;
arr[10] = "ten";

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

## 2. Does `forEach` use an internal counter

### Answer: yes

You can get a hold of the current result easily, since it's passed into the callback.

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "five";
arr[42] = "the answer";
arr[9001] = "over nine thousand";

arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(index, "-", item);
});
```

## 3. What order does `forEach` go in

### Answer: starts from zero and it goes in ascending order

The above should show you that. Here is another quick example:

```js
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" ];

alphabet.forEach(function(letter, index) {
  console.log(index, letter);
})
```

## 4. Differences between `for` and `forEach`

### Answer: hard to compare them

The *differences* between the two are what I alluded to in the beginning - `for` is a generic loop operator in JavaScript - you *can* use it to go through arrays but you can use it for various other purposes, too. `forEach`, by contrast, is specifically bound to arrays. It's very hard to compare the two realistically but if we restrict to *only* talking about using them on arrays, here are some points

### `for`

- + You can exit a loop early using `break` or `return`, so you don't need to loop over the entire array
- + You can control the array traversal, so you can start from the end and count down (`for (var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--)`) or perhaps even go back or skip items (doing `i--` or `i += 2` inside the loop body)
- + Well recognised as a looping mechanism as it's used in a lot of other languages
- +/- You will loop over the entire array length, even for sparse arrays.
- - You have to maintain the loop counter even if you don't care about it.

### `forEach`

- + Deals well with sparse arrays
- + Accepts callbacks, so you can re-use functions by passing them into the `.forEach` call
- + Another benefit of the above is the functional scope for everything inside the body of the callback (although with ES6 `let` and `const` that matters less)
- + Idiomatic JavaScript
- +/- You will go over only present items in a sparse array
- - Cannot exit early, although, you might be able to use `find`.
- - You have no control of the how the array is traversed.

## PS: Honourable mention goes to `for...of`

Thanks to @Bergi, I remembered something that I did want to include here:

One loop you didn't mention but exists is the [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which is *similar* in syntax to the `for...in` loop but it is designed to work on arrays as well as other iterable objects. It is a relatively new construct (newer than `forEach` at least) as it is in the ES6 specifications, so wide web-support *might* not be there but it is an alternative to both of the above. It is pretty simple to use:

```js
var arr = [];
arr[5] = "five";
arr[7] = "seven";
arr[10] = "ten";

for (item of arr) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

So, in short, it works like a `for` loop since it goes over everything, but you don't have to declare and maintain a counter.

Comment: Whether `forEach` deals "well" with sparse arrays is debatable, many would expect to get `undefined` values instead of skipping.

Comment: I would consider `for` and `for…of` much more idiomatic than `.forEach`

Comment: @Bergi about sparse arrays, that will probably depend on how you want to process them. In my experience, most of the time I would only want what is present in them, although I would say that's not _all_ the time. I can definitely see use for looping over everything. However, it seems like JavaScript (or perhaps ECMAScript) has taken the stance that sparse arrays should only consist of any of its existing members. So, "well" might need to be qualified there, but for some use cases, it fits.

Comment: @Bergi and about `for`, it's idiomatic everywhere, (probably should have phrased it that way, instead of "Well recognised") but I wouldn't consider it JS specific. The array methods like `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `find` are more distinct JavaScript. Sure, they exist outside of it, but when talking about JS array handling mechanisms, they deserve their spot, which does make them stand out and well recognised.

Answer (score 1):

vlaz has already answered in comments, I would just had:

The main difference is that the `forEach` call can generate one closure by element in the array, which is very useful when you need to reuse some internal variables.